# Display thinking it's large-12 when it should be small-12

Tags: windows-phone-8, zurb-foundation

I have a really annoying problem, I'm trying to make a web page that will scale well across large resolutions and mobile devices / tablets.

On a large screen, I want things to appear like this:

```
---------------------
|    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |
---------------------
```

But on a small screen, I want things to appear like this:

```
---------------------
|                   |  
|                   |
---------------------
---------------------
|                   |  
|                   |
---------------------
---------------------
|                   |  
|                   |
---------------------
---------------------
|                   |  
|                   |
---------------------
```

My markup looks like this ([here's a quick jsFiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/Nxmm7/1/)):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 large-3 columns"></div>
    <div class="small-12 large-3 columns"></div>
    <div class="small-12 large-3 columns"></div>
    <div class="small-12 large-3 columns"></div>
</div>
```

Everything is working well on a PC and iPhone, yet when I try things on Windows Mobile (Nokia Lumia 820) it's thinking it's large and displaying the former instead of the latter... and it's driving me insane!!

I've put the usual meta viewport `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1">` and have even tried `width=320` to try and trick it into thinking it's smaller.

Any advice?

Comment: On a side note, I don't understand the purpose of your second line (`<div class="small-12 large-12 columns">`). You're putting columns inside a column without encapsulating them in a new row. In this case, that whole line seems unnecessary too.

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes well spotted, that was a bit of a copy-paste mistake from my working code. Corrected.

Comment: If I'd have to make a guess, it might have something to do with the screen size of the Lumia. It's apparently 800 pixels long. Foundation has a breakpoint at 768px (anything below that is considered a small screen). [Source: http://smartphones.findthebest.com/q/373/4941/How-big-is-the-screen-on-the-Nokia-Lumia-820-smartphone.]

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes I thought that too, hence the setting of `width=320` to the `viewport` to try and circumvent the default 800px. It doesn't look like Windows Mobile is honouring the `viewport` tag at all though.

Comment: Apparently i.e. on windows phone doesn't play nicely with the meta viewport tag. Try taking out "initial-scale=1", and if that doesn't work, here's a blog article about this exact problem:
http://mattstow.com/responsive-design-in-ie10-on-windows-phone-8.html

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer in Windows Phone 8 can be configured to behave as a desktop or a mobile browser.

Go to Settings and set the `Website preference` to be either "mobile version" or "desktop version". This will affect the way the browser behaves.

If the browser is set to "desktop version" you won't be able to avoid this as it assumes a wider viewport and hence the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried this (it doesn't work in either mode) and it's definitely set to "mobile version" for all websites.